# ASP.NET Core MVC route to controller any child url like "admin/*"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to route any url address like `/admin/*` as my admin is on Angular2 and uses its routing. I tried `template: "admin/{*url}"`though it works not only with `/admin` url but with any other. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: what do you mean by "though it works not only with /admin url but with any other" would you please give an example of a route that works and another route that doesn't work?

Comment: I think he means the issue is that *all* routes are handled by the `admin/{*url}` handler?

Comment: @HaithamShaddad I mean that `NotAdmin/NotExistingPage` is handled by `AdminController`.

Comment: Just make the route as: `template: "admin/"` no need for the `{*url}` beacuse you say this route has Angualr2 aready handles its routes using HTML5 URL or #

Comment: @OleksiiKryzh, Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in your WebApiConfig.cs file :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "some name",
              routeTemplate: "admin/{*url}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Your default action here" });
```

Set the default controller in defaults.